# Using Virtual desktop in Dual Monitors

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop, virtual-desktop-manager

i am trying to set a dual monitor rig in windows and i was hoping to see if i can set virtual desktops simultaneously running on two different screens. so far i have tried using different tools like actual multiple monitors and sysinternal virtual desktops but i cant find the option anywhere. is it possible to achieve what i am trying?

i just want to use two different screens at same time with two virtual desktops, and yes i know about extended desktop and i dont want to use that option.
i am using win 8.1.

Comment: "if i can set virtual desktops simultaneously running on two different screens." - Windows 8.1 does not have virtual desktops, that is a feature limited to, Windows 10+.  Windows 10 only allows you to have a single active virtual desktop, like all versions of Windows, the desktop itself is constant across all displays.  What you want to do would require third-party software.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the virtual desktop tools you mentioned, but I am using Dexpot myself and I know it has support for multiple monitors with each its own settings.

http://dexpot.de/

Comment: i am open for commercial tools but does it provide the functionality to run different desktop on diff screens , thanks

Comment: dexpot is free for personal use, and yes, it does allow to run different desktops on different screens.

Comment: I thought I would quote this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_desktop), which states that, "There is no native and easy way for users to create their own desktops or populate them with programs.  However, there are many third-party (e. g. VirtuaWin, Dexpot and others) and some partially supported Microsoft products that implement virtual desktops to varying degrees of completeness."